# How to check if a dictionary matches another dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pattern-matching

How do I check if a dictionary matches another dictionary? For example, given 2 dictionaries

```
{
    name: "Alice",
    lives: {
        city: "Venice",
        since: 2000
    }
}

{
    name: "Bob",
    lives: {
        city: "Hong Kong"
    }
}
```

match with

```
{
    name: "^A.*", <- a regexp
    lives: {
        since: "*" <- must have this key too
    }
}
```

and the function will return True or False.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to create a custom class with a `validation` method, and use specific values for the field when building the match object:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import re
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class City:
    name: str
    since: Optional[int] = None

    def __str__(self):
        if self.since is not None:
            return f"{self.name} since {self.since}"
        else:
            return f"{self.name}"

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    lives: City

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} lives in {self.lives}"

    def validate(self, match_spec):
        valid = True

        # validate the name
        m = re.match(match_spec.name, self.name)
        if m is not None:
            print(f"Name {self.name} does not match {match_spec.name}")
            valid = False

        # check if the spec requires the year
        if match_spec.lives.since is not None:
            if self.lives.since is None:
                print(f"Missing year for {self.name}.")
                valid = False

        if valid:
            print("Correct validation")

alice = Person("Alice", City("Venice", 2000))
print(alice)
bob = Person("Bob", City("Hong Kong"))
print(bob)

# we change the semantic of person.lives.since:
# a not None value means that we want to check that the field exists
match_spec_1 = Person("^A.*", City(".*", 1))

print(f"\nValidate '{alice}' with '{match_spec_1}''")
alice.validate(match_spec_1)

print(f"\nValidate '{bob}' with '{match_spec_1}'")
bob.validate(match_spec_1)

match_spec_2 = Person("^B.*", City(".*"))

print(f"\nValidate '{alice}' with '{match_spec_2}'")
alice.validate(match_spec_2)

print(f"\nValidate '{bob}' with '{match_spec_2}'")
bob.validate(match_spec_2)
```

This prints:

```
Alice lives in Venice since 2000
Bob lives in Hong Kong

Validate 'Alice lives in Venice since 2000' with '^A.* lives in .* since 1''
Correct validation

Validate 'Bob lives in Hong Kong' with '^A.* lives in .* since 1'
Name Bob does not match ^A.*
Missing year for Bob.

Validate 'Alice lives in Venice since 2000' with '^B.* lives in .*'
Name Alice does not match ^B.*

Validate 'Bob lives in Hong Kong' with '^B.* lives in .*'
Correct validation
```

And you could easily add checks on the city name and so on.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hard code the spec, the solution is fairly easy.

```
import re

def meets_spec(dic):
    # Here we just assume the pattern is constant
    pattern = re.compile(r'^A.*')
    # if the pattern has matches and the key 'since'
    # is in the 'lives' dict, return True
    if re.match(pattern, dic.get('name', '')):
        # .get() is nice here because it doesn't raise an
        # error when the key doesn't exist. It just
        # returns False and moves on
        if 'since' in dic.get('lives', {}):
            return True
    return False

dict_1 = {
    'name': 'Alice',
    'lives': {
        'city': 'Venice',
        'since': 2000
    }
}
dict_2 = {
    'name': 'Bob',
    'lives': {
        'city': 'Hong Kong'
    }
}
print(meets_spec(dict_1))
print(meets_spec(dict_2))
```

Now let's assume you want to be a bit more dynamic and have a function that accepts any such spec.

```
import re

def meets_spec(dic, spec, required='*'):
    # by default we return True
    # and conditionally prove ourselves False
    result = True
    for k, v in spec.items():
        # this assumes an asterisk is a required item
        # but still allows what defines required to be changed
        if v == required:
            if k not in dic:
                result = False
        # it checks nested dicts recursively
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            # .get() is used for the same reasons above.
            if not meets_spec(dic.get(k, {}), v):
                result = False
        # and it assumes anything that isn't an asterisk
        # or a nested dict is a regular expression.
        else:
            pattern = re.compile(v)
            if not re.match(pattern, dic.get(k, '')):
                result = False
    return result

dict_1 = {
    'name': 'Alice',
    'lives': {
        'city': 'Venice',
        'since': 2000
    }
}
dict_2 = {
    'name': 'Bob',
    'lives': {
        'city': 'Hong Kong'
    }
}
spec = {
    'name': '^A.*',
    'lives': {
        'since': '*'
    }
}
print(meets_spec(dict_1, spec))
print(meets_spec(dict_2, spec))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is the best solution that I've read so far. I was hoping that there would be some Python built-in function that I could reuse for this instead of rolling my own. Do you have any idea if Python or the "re" module have this function already built in?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But then again, most of what I use from `re` are just the typical `re.match()` which is shown above and `re.findall()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

a = {
    'name': "Alice",
    'lives': {
        'city': "Venice",
        'since': 2000
    }
}

b = {
    'name': "Bob",
    'lives': {
        'city': "Hong Kong"
    }
}

match_with = {
    'name': "^A.*",
    'lives': {
        'since': "*"
    }
}

matched = {
    'name': False,
    'since': False
}


def match_dict(dictionary, match_with):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if k in match_with:
            if type(v) == dict:
                match_dict(v, match_with[k])
            if k == 'name':
                if re.match(match_with[k], dictionary[k]):
                    matched['name'] = True
                    continue
            elif k == 'since':
                matched['since'] = True

    if False in matched.values():
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

maybe this will help